# Issue while deploying PHP application to Apache server Httpd

Tags: php, linux, apache, http, centos

I have an application primarily written in PHP and using jQuery. I have a fresh CentOS VM where I copied application name RCCA under `system-test/eabu-tools` directory and created a link RCCA inside `/var/www/html` directory.

Contents of `/var/www/html` shown below.

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   27 Aug  6 12:04 RCCA -> system-test/eabu-tools/RCCA
```

Application Name is RCCA which have soft link called RCCA inside `/var/www/html` directory as shown above.

When I am accessing the application using url `http://hostname/RCCA/rcca.php`.  All I am getting is a blank page and when I look at the source of the page I get the following output but nothing further, or includes are not working.

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
      <? include "header.php"?>
      <?php include "navbar.php" ?>
    </div>
    <div id="context_container">
        <div id="context_content">
            <div id="navi"></div>
            <div id="tabs-left">
                <? include("tabsTemplate.php");?>
                <div id="tabs-1" name="all-stats"> 
                    <div id="tabs-content"> 
                      <? include("all_rcca_sections.php");?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="tabs-2" name="stats1">
                    <div id="tabs-content"> 
                      <? include("rcca_sections1.php");?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="tabs-4">
                    <div id="tabs-content" name="stats2"> 
                      <? include("rcca_sections2.php");?>
                    </div>
                </div> ... so on.
```

Also, same directory structure and application is working fine on another server. Any idea what I am missing as first PHP deployment on fresh VM?

Comment: Looks like PHP is not running on the server, if you see php tags in browser. Also short open tags <? won't work on newer PHP versions.

Comment: @Alex2php, do i need to start any particular module to run php or any idea for backward compatibility?

Comment: Check if PHP is running on the server with `php -v`, if not you need to install it like `sudo yum install php`. Here is a complete guide to install a LAMP Stack with CentOS: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-centos-7

Comment: @Alex2php, Yes, php is running. Out put is 
[root@eabu-www-shell03 html]# php -v
PHP 5.1.6 (cli) (built: Jun 27 2012 12:21:13)
Copyright (c) 1997-2006 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2006 Zend Technologies

Comment: @Alex2php "sudo yum install php" fix the issue. Please put in answer section so that i can accept it as an Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If php code shows up in browser, PHP is not running as a (apache module) on the server. This is how you can install PHP on CentOS:

```
sudo yum install php
```

Also you should replace the short open tags, as they are disabled by default in newer PHP versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `<?php include ("file.php")?>` in all includes.

Comment: What is the content in the file included? html tags and texts? Try to add <?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ?> at first line and check for results